# Android Room obtain reference to parent in one-to-many relationship

Tags: android, android-room

in my app I have two tables with a one to many relationship between them. Movie, and Genre, each movie has one genre. In an extended ArrayAdapter that displays a list of movies, I want to have a different color for the movie depending on genre, that is defined in the genre class. This would be easy to do if I had a reference to genre from movie, so I could do `movie.getGenre().getColor()`. But Room forbids this, and I dont want to have to do a search for the genre based on its id for each entry in the movie list.

In essence, how can I quickly and efficiently obtain a reference to the parent class, from the child class, when using Android Room. Relations allow me to easily query a genre with all of its movies, but not the other way around. I want to end up with a list of movies, and a list of genres, and I want each movie to hold a reference to the genre that is its.

I'm suprised to not see this problem come up on google. How is this problem usually solved?

Comment: can you show your @Entity for ```movie``` and ```genre```? There is an ```@Embbded``` for ```RoomDB``` for one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the list of movies and corresponding genres, we should model the one-to-one relationship between the two entities.

1. Create a class for two entities:

   ```
    data class MovieAndGenre(
        @Embedded val movie: Movie,
        @Relation(
             parentColumn = "genre_id",  // as named in Movie table             
             entityColumn = "_id"  // as named Genre table
        )
        val genre: Genre
    )
   ```
2. Add a method in Dao to fetch all instances for parent and child pair

   ```
   @Transaction
   @Query("SELECT * FROM movie")
   fun getMoviesAndGenres(): List<MovieAndGenre>
   ```

Note: Implementation might change based on the way your entities are structured. But you get an idea of how you achieve what you want.

If you want to learn more about Room relationships check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement this, it's counter intuitive to me, because in my head it's a one-to-many relationship, because  a genre has many movies